# Build c program for release and build

Tags: c, makefile

The original makefile comes for Release build.

**Original**

```
APP:= deepstream-app

TARGET_DEVICE = $(shell gcc -dumpmachine | cut -f1 -d -)

NVDS_VERSION:=5.0

LIB_INSTALL_DIR?=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-$(NVDS_VERSION)/lib/
APP_INSTALL_DIR?=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-$(NVDS_VERSION)/bin/

ifeq ($(TARGET_DEVICE),aarch64)
  CFLAGS:= -DPLATFORM_TEGRA
endif

SRCS:= $(wildcard *.c)
SRCS+= $(wildcard ../../apps-common/src/*.c)

INCS:= $(wildcard *.h)

PKGS:= gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 x11

OBJS:= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS+= -I../../apps-common/includes -I../../../includes -DDS_VERSION_MINOR=0 -DDS_VERSION_MAJOR=5

LIBS+= -L$(LIB_INSTALL_DIR) -lnvdsgst_meta -lnvds_meta -lnvdsgst_helper -lnvdsgst_smartrecord -lnvds_utils -lm \
       -lgstrtspserver-1.0 -ldl -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)

CFLAGS+= `pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS)`

LIBS+= `pkg-config --libs $(PKGS)`

all: $(APP)

%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC)  -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

$(APP): $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(CC) -o $(APP) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

install: $(APP)
    cp -rv $(APP) $(APP_INSTALL_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(APP)
```

**Modified for both Release and Debug**

```
APP:= deepstream-app
DEBUGAPP:= deepstream-app-debug

TARGET_DEVICE = $(shell gcc -dumpmachine | cut -f1 -d -)

NVDS_VERSION:=5.0

LIB_INSTALL_DIR?=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-$(NVDS_VERSION)/lib/
APP_INSTALL_DIR?=/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-$(NVDS_VERSION)/bin/

ifeq ($(TARGET_DEVICE),aarch64)
  CFLAGS:= -DPLATFORM_TEGRA
endif

SRCS:= $(wildcard *.c)
SRCS+= $(wildcard ../../apps-common/src/*.c)

INCS:= $(wildcard *.h)

PKGS:= gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 x11

OBJS:= $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS+= -I../../apps-common/includes -I../../../includes -DDS_VERSION_MINOR=0 -DDS_VERSION_MAJOR=5

LIBS+= -L$(LIB_INSTALL_DIR) -lnvdsgst_meta -lnvds_meta -lnvdsgst_helper -lnvdsgst_smartrecord -lnvds_utils -lm \
       -lgstrtspserver-1.0 -ldl -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB_INSTALL_DIR)

CFLAGS+= `pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS)`

LIBS+= `pkg-config --libs $(PKGS)`

all: $(APP)

%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC)  -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC) -g3  -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

$(APP): $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(CC) -o $(APP) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
$(DEBUGAPP): $(OBJS) Makefile
    $(CC) -g3 -o $(DEBUGAPP) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

install: $(APP)
    cp -rv $(APP) $(DEBUGAPP) $(APP_INSTALL_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(APP) $(DEBUGAPP)
```

But it doesn't produce deepstream-app-debug. What should I change for both release and debug?

Comment: `all: $(APP)` The default target only builds the release version. So did you explicitly tell make during invocation to build the debug version? That is, what is your `make` command? Or you can modify the default target to include the `DEBUGAPP`.

Comment: how can i include DEBUGAPP?

Comment: @kaylum How can I tell make during invocation to build the debug version?

Comment: regarding: `%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC)  -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
%.o: %.c $(INCS) Makefile
    $(CC) -g3  -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<`   the `make` utility will execute the first compile rule, then the `%.o` will be up-to-date, so the second compile rule will never be executed

Comment: Why does this question have the 'c++' and 'c++17' tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `DEBUGAPP` to the target `all`:

```
# This belongs in the makefile:
all: $(APP) $(DEBUGAPP)
```

This will build both `APP` and `DEBUGAPP`, if you call `make` like you used to do it most probably.

However, you can give `make` any target as an argument without further changing the makefile:

```
# This is a command in your shell:
make deepstream-app-debug
```

Comment: yes it works. Thanks. I missed all: $(APP) $(DEBUGAPP)

Comment: Small error: It should be `make deepstream-app-debug`. `DEBUGAPP` is a variable and not a target that can be directly made.